# Put Duplicates under Common Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code.

```
<ul id="listOne">
    <li class="columnItem>John</li>
    <li class="columnItem>James</li>
    <li class="columnItem>Mary</li>
</ul>

<ul id="listTwo">
    <li class="columnItem>John</li>
    <li class="columnItem>Mark</li>
    <li class="columnItem>Mary</li>
</ul>
```

I want to remove the duplicate list items from both list and place it under another list as "CommonList". Something like

```
<ul id="CommmonList">
    <li class="columnItem>John</li>
    <li class="columnItem>Mary</li>
</ul>
<ul id="listOne">
    <li class="columnItem>James</li>        
</ul>

<ul id="listTwo">
    <li class="columnItem>Mark</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Fine. What have you tried and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Note, `html` is missing closing quote at `class` value

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using [ES6 Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

Here is what you could do.

```js
$(() => {

  let names = [];
  let nameSet = new Set();

  $("li.columnItem").each((idx, ele) => {
    nameSet.add($(ele).html())
  });

  var $common = $("<ul>").addClass("commmonList");
  nameSet.forEach((name) => {
    if ($("li:contains(" + name + ")").length > 1) {
      $("li:contains(" + name + ")").remove();
      $("<li>").addClass("columnItem").html(name).appendTo($common);
    }
  });
  $common.appendTo($("div"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul id="listOne">
    <li class="columnItem">John</li>
    <li class="columnItem">James</li>
    <li class="columnItem">Mary</li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="listTwo">
    <li class="columnItem">John</li>
    <li class="columnItem">Mark</li>
    <li class="columnItem">Mary</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: +Sreekanth The above code only works if the list already exists on HTML not when dynamically creating the list. I will be building the list by Ajax query. really appreciate in if you can show me how to implement the above code dynamically as the list is built on click event.

Comment: In that case, would you be getting a list of values?

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery Each function](https://api.jquery.com/each/) will help you in this problem. You can traverse all list items with a for loop as you see below.

This is the basic solution working in O(n^2), you can use more effective algorithm to compare list elements.

```js
$("#duplicate").on('click',function(){
    var CommmonListHtml = "<ul id='CommmonList'>";

    $( "#listOne li" ).each(function( index_one ) {
        thiz = $(this);
        $( "#listTwo li" ).each(function( index ) {
            if(thiz.text() == $(this).text()){
                CommmonListHtml += "<li>"+$(this).text()+"</li>";
                thiz.remove();
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    });

    CommmonListHtml += "</ul>";

    $("div.lists").prepend(CommmonListHtml);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='lists'>
    <ul id="listOne">
        <li class="columnItem">John</li>
        <li class="columnItem">James</li>
        <li class="columnItem">Mary</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="listTwo">
        <li class="columnItem">John</li>
        <li class="columnItem">Mark</li>
        <li class="columnItem">Mary</li>
    </ul>
    <a href='#' id='duplicate'>Remove Duplicates</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#listOne li").each(function(a,c){
$("#listTwo li").each(function(b,d){
if($(c).html()==$(d).html()){
  var re=$(c).remove()[0];
   $(d).remove();
  $("#CommmonList").append(re);
}
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="listOne">
    <li class="columnItem">John</li>
    <li class="columnItem">James</li>
    <li class="columnItem">Mary</li>
</ul>

<ul id="listTwo">
    <li class="columnItem">John</li>
    <li class="columnItem">Mark</li>
    <li class="columnItem">Mary</li>
</ul>
<ul id="CommmonList">
    
</ul>
```